# Is loading PHP pages with AJAX good practice?

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, seo

I have a PHP website with four or five other PHP files that I load onto the main index.php using jQuery AJAX.  Is this good practice as far as SEO and web crawlers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No inherently, I would suggest you read this. As well there is a tool at the bottom to help you see what a google spider sees.

https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started

Comment: Thanks the info was helpful

Comment: You're welcome, if you found this sufficient please select this as the answer when you can.